# Limit and Offset many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I get stack in my database, my problem is i Have 3 tables and 2 have many to many relationship, the other one is gernerate from 2 tables.

I want paging follow 1 table, it mean 2 table parent and i want to paging follow 1 of 2 table parents row

Example

Table Customer :

> ID     Name                Email
>
> 1      Peter               peter@gmail.com
>
> 2      Jonh               john@gmai.com
>
> 3     Sara                sara@gmail.com
>
> 4     Tom                 tom@gmail.com
>
> 5     Jet                 jet@gmail.com

2 table products

> ID      -----   Product Name
>   1       -----   Shampoo
>   2       -----   Coca
>   3       -----   Hotdog
>   4       -----   Kit kat
>   5       -----   Cheese
>   6       -----   Pasta
>   7       -----   Chocolate
>   8       -----   Peanut Butter
>   9       -----   Hamburger
>   10      -----  Sandwich

Table CustomerBuyProduct

```
ID CusID   ProductID
1    1        1
2    1        3
3    1        4
4    2        1 
5    2        10
6    3        4
7    3        10
8    3         2
9    3         6
10   3         5
11   3         3
12   4         1
13   5         1
```

And my problem is when i select and left join 3 tables they will show me 11 rows, yes it right because i want to get all rows from three tables
but i want paging follow Customer Table, it mean in page 1 just 3 rows or 5 rows it will show total customers in Customer Table and product they buy look like

Total :3 Rows

```
 No.      Customer Name             Bought Product
                                            Shampoo
    1        Peter                          Coca
                                            Hotdog

    2       Jonh                           Shampoo
                                           Sandwich

                                           Kitkat
                                           Sandwich
    3       Sara                           Coca
                                           Cheese
                                           Hotdog

                         Page 1/2
```

Total: 2 rows

```
    4      Tom                           Shampoo

    5      Jet                           Shampoo
```

But i have no idea to make select statement for this case
Anyone can help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: Show the query you have written to get this far, anf the PHP code that is controlling it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GROUP_CONCAT` with a `GROUP BY Customer.ID` clause.

```
SELECT 
    Customer.ID, Customer.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(products.Name SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM
    Customer LEFT JOIN
    CustomerBuyProduct ON CusID = Customer.ID LEFT JOIN
    products ON ProductID = products.ID
GROUP BY
    Customer.ID
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Sorry, if i want to show data in table how can i do it look like table i gave u in my example 1 row customer will rowspan for 2 or more products, because group concat will merge rows into 1 row

Comment: What if you used a <br> tag for the separator like
    GROUP_CONCAT(products.Name SEPARATOR '<br>') 
would that work? I suppose you could also do something like
    GROUP_CONCAT(products.Name SEPARATOR '</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td>')

Comment: i try your way but when i search follow your query, the customer who bought 2 items will show the same item name. Example Customer ID : 2 Name: Peter - Bought Sandwich and Coca. But when i Search Like San, the query would return Sandwich </td></tr><tr><td>Sanwich, it didnt return only sandwich

Comment: my query `SELECT 
     Customer.ID, Customer.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(product.PName SEPARATOR '</td></tr><tr><td>') 
FROM
    Customer LEFT JOIN
    pcu ON customerid = Customer.ID LEFT JOIN
    product ON productid = product.PID
WHERE product.PNAME like '%sh%'    
GROUP BY Customer.ID`

Comment: Try replacing `WHERE product.PNAME like` with `WHERE GROUP_CONCAT(product.PNAME) like`.

Comment: i try to did it follow your guide but i got a error message `#1111 - Invalid use of group function `

Comment: I forgot you can't use a group function in a where statement. Remove the where clause entirely. Then at the end of the sql query add `HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(product.PNAME) like '%sh%'`. So the whole query should look like `SELECT Customer.ID, Customer.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(product.PName SEPARATOR '</td></tr><tr><td>') FROM Customer LEFT JOIN pcu ON customerid = Customer.ID LEFT JOIN product ON productid = product.PID GROUP BY Customer.ID HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(product.PNAME) like '%sh%'`

Comment: Thank you @programmerKev but it show me 2 rows  Sandwich and Shampoo. although i wanna get 1 shampoo instead of both

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Try the query you posted 5 comments above this one. But add `DISTINCT` to the `GROUP_CONTACT`. So it would be: `SELECT Customer.ID, Customer.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product.PName SEPARATOR '</td></tr><tr><td>') FROM Customer LEFT JOIN pcu ON customerid = Customer.ID LEFT JOIN product ON productid = product.PID WHERE product.PNAME like '%sh%' GROUP BY Customer.ID`.